# How to reference the struct in the same package

Tags: go, package, mux

I am trying to build a web app with two files.

`app.go` and `main.go` are both in the same directory.

app.go

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type App struct {
    Router *mux.Router
    DB *sql.DB
}

func (a *App) Initialize(username, password, server, port, dbName, cacheAddr, cachePass string){
}


func (a *App) Run(addr string) {
}
```

main.go

```
package main

func main() {
    a := App{}
    // more code here
}
```

I thought my `main.go` file would recognize `App{}` but my editor is complaining that `App` is undeclared name

Both files are in the same main package but I am not sure what went wrong. Could anyone help me about it? Thank you!

Comment: is it running properly when you run go run . or go run main.go app.go ?

Comment: which editor is you are using?

Comment: vscode and it complains the same error if I do "go run main.go"

Comment: you should pass app.go as well when running the program. try like this go run main.go app.go

Comment: Never, ever use `go run main.go`.   Use `go run .` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments I assume you run the following command: `go run main.go`. This will ONLY load code in `main.go` (and files included with `import` statements). To tell Go to load all `.go` files in the current directory, run the following instead:

```
go run .
```

Similarly, to tell VSCode to load alll files start it like this:

```
code .
```